# Why is sys.argv() giving me an index out of bound?

Tags: python

I have a textile with content like this:

```
honda motor co of japan doesn't expect output at its car manufacturing plant in thailand
```

When I run wc -l textfile.txt, I receive 0.

The problem is I am running a python script that needs to count the number of line in this text file and run accordingly. I have tried two ways of computing the number of lines but they both keep giving me 0 and my code refuses to run.

Python code:

```
#Way 1
with open(sys.argv[1]) as myfile:
    row=sum(1 for line in myfile)
print(row)

#Way 2
row = run("cat %s | wc -l" % sys.argv[1]).split()[0]
```

I receive an error that says: `with open(sys.argv[1]) as myfile IndexError: list index out of range`

I am calling receiving this file from php:

```
exec('python testthis.py $file 2>&1', $output);
```

I suspect that argv.sys[1] is giving me an error.

Comment: If `sys.argv[1]` is throwing an `IndexError` then it doesn't have a second element. Have you tried looking at what it does contain?

Comment: It sounds like `$file` is expanding to an empty string, so you are invoking your Python program with no argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the first example of your Python code (way 1).

The problem is the PHP calling code; the string being passed to `exec()` uses [single quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) which prevents the expansion of the `$file` variable into the command string. The resulting call therefore passes the literal string `$file` as the argument to `exec()`, which in turn runs the command in a shell. That shell treats `$file` as a shell variable and tries to expand it, but it is not defined, and so it expands to an empty string. The resulting call is:

```
python testthis.py 2>&1
```

to which Python raises `IndexError: list index out of range` because it is missing an argument.

To fix use [*double quotes*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) around the command when calling `exec()` in PHP:

```
$file = 'test.txt';
exec("python testthis.py $file 2>&1", $output);
```

Now `$file` can be expanded into the string as required.

This does assume that you actually want to expand a PHP variable into the string. Because `exec()` runs the command in a shell, it is also possible to have the variable defined in the shell's environment, and it will be expanded by the shell into the final command. To do this you *would* use single quotes around the command passed to `exec()`.

---

Note that the Python code of "way 1" will return a line count of 1, not 0 as does `wc -l`.